# Sitecore forms custom field override validation error message

Tags: sitecore-forms, mvc-forms

I have added a RichtextCheckbox custom field in Sitecore forms.

[image: RichTex]

I have added validation and it's working fine.

This is the razor code

```
<label class="@Model.LabelCssClass">
    <input type="checkbox" id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.IsChecked)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass" @if (Model.IsChecked) { <text> checked="checked" </text> } value="true" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" />@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)
    @Html.Raw(Model.RichText)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)
</label>
```

I want to override the validation error message. Currently, if the checkbox is not checked then the error is "is required". I want to override the error message. How can I do that?

Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

That is the default error message for mandatory fields.
[This blog post](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/10/sitecore-9-forms-translating-error.html) describes how you can change that:

> The code for the required field validation works in a different way
> and the message will come from the Sitecore dictionary. If you want to
> update or translate it, you need to add a key to that Dictionary. This
> can be done in the master database - just add an item in the
> /system/Dictionary - the name doesn't really matter. The key however
> needs to be exactly "{0} is required.". The phrase can be anything you
> want, just remember to add the {0} token.
> [image]

Note that this would change the message for all mandatory fields.

If you want something specific, you'll need to create a custom validation.
You can read [here](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/10/sitecore-9-forms-custom-validation.html) or [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-custom-validation.html) how.